# Grout and/or thinset flushed in septic system

Tags: plumbing, concrete, grout, septic

All.

My contractor is awful. If we weren't almost done with the project, I would kick him off my property and sue him.

Anyway, it appears that he dumped excess thinset or grout into my basement toilet. It caused a backup in my basement tub, toilet, and sink. It looks like someone hastily cleaned it up, but only a little. I have now cleaned it from the room and everything is flushing and draining normally.

However, we have a septic system. Will we need to have the septic tank pumped?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would call a plumber that has a snake with a camera to inspect the drains to see if the thinset or anything else has plugged or partially restricted the drains. A partial restriction can result in debris plugging that line from time to time and certain types of tissue getting caught by a rough surface. It would be better to fix the problem now than having issues at a later date.  my 2 cents

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without knowing how much was dumped. The toxicity to the septic tank flora is fairly low however. It certainly is not going to break down however, so it is a permanent deposit at best case.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the covers on the septic,and look for grout at the end where waste first enters. Grout may thin out and settle on the bottom . Or be stuck on the first wall. If you have a pumped system, pull pump out,and check it over. Then you can choose to pump or not.